# Using New HTML5 Tags

Tags: css, html, tags

I'm trying new HTML5 tags. I want to do something like this : http://www.jsfiddle.net/TYTkZ/

I'm using this code : http://www.jsfiddle.net/cysBf/

You will see the difference when you click link. Can you help me ? Why there is space between #main and #sidebar sections?

And page    hierarchy  is true ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this code in your css:

```
header,footer,article,section,aside,nav {
  display:block;
}
```

I updated your code in jsfiddle.

Comment: Unsupported elements will turn into inline elements in browsers; there's no need to turn them in block elements

Answer (score 2):

When using HTML5 elements remember to include this file before any CSS etc (*so the top of the head tag would be best*).

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
```

Because IE 8 and below do not know the the HTML5 elements they will not let you style them, this script allows the styling of HTML5 elements in older IEs.

**EDIT**

I know this is not his direct question but no one should make this mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `float:right` on #sidebar, so the element will end up all the way to the right.
Try `float:left` on #sidebar to make it float next to the #main element

The width of 300px is ignored because section is not defined as `display:block`

Comment: But i'm setting width of #cont to 300 px. Why #sidebar floating to page's right ? It should float to #cont's right.

Comment: I'm adding display:block; . Is this enough ?